# Snap.svg failing to .transform() for <use> tag element

Tags: svg, snap.svg

I have an use element in my svg like

```
<use x="47.46" y="44.64" cx="48" cy="45" id="9zh7" href="#msi_plane" class="markerpoint"></use>
```

I have a hover function which transform .markerpoint class element on hover:-

```
$('.markerpoint').hover(
    function() {
      var mySnapElement = Snap(this);
      mySnapElement.transform('s1.5');
    }
    function() {
      mySnapElement.transform('s1');
    }
)
```

Transform is **working fine for other element** of svg like <circle ....> or <rect ....> ***but throwing error for <use ...>  tag***

**Error response data:-**

```
snap.svg.js:2786 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'substring')
    at Element.elproto.getBBox (snap.svg.js:2786)
    at extractTransform (snap.svg.js:2834)
    at Element.elproto.transform (snap.svg.js:2896)
    at SVGUseElement.<anonymous> (main.js:1023)
    at SVGUseElement.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
    at SVGUseElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at SVGUseElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
```

**Seems like it is limitation of Snap.svg in handling <use**>

**Looking for hacks or suggestion for way forward**

Comment: @RobertLongson Thank you! you pointed it correctly. now hover over the <use> is not throwing error but on transforming it apart from scaling its size to 1.5 it is also translating <use> in both x and y. thus <use> is not zooming on its own location.

for example hovering over <circle> produces matrix like this
matrix(1.5,0,0,1.5,-226.3881,-340.458)
but hovering over <use> producing this
matrix(1.5,0,0,1.5,0,0).
Missing e, f correction for <use> is culprit.
Dont know where problem lies. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Although I have achieved the desired effect by replacing mySnapElement.transform('s1.5'); with  var rmatx=mySnapElement.transform().localMatrix.scale(1.5, 1.5, [cx], [cy]); mySnapElement.transform(rmatx); but if u wish then can tell why mySnapElement.transform('s1.5'); was failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems from a quick perusal of [the source code](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/blob/master/src/element.js#L68) that Snap.svg does not support bare href but requires you to use xlink:href

The use of href is new in SVG 2, SVG 1.1 was xlink:href only.